# Sqlite3 database Standards and properties : From .CSV or .XLS to .sqlite in Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, csv, xls

Hy,
What are the standards/properties needed to be chosen and checked while converting a.xls or .csv file to a .sqlite file.
What should i pay attention to and be careful of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the simplest way is to import it from a .xls file, using NAVICAT FOR SQLITE. Using any other software may cause some problems..